# Jump to newly generated row in excel with VB

Tags: excel, vba, row

Hallo dear Stackoverflow users,

I searched on google and the so forum, but haven't found anything.

I am working with an excel similar too for reporting. In this report a user can create a new instance. Many instances can be created.

**When a new measure is created new rows are created and the information of the measure is saved in these new rows.**

When a new measure is created **the new measure isn't always all at the bottom of the measure list**, but is somewhere in the list, since it is a ordered list.

My question is the following. I **need to be able to see the last created measure by having the cursor move automatically to the last generated row.**

Either by searching all the values in a column and then going to the cell that contains that specific value, or by jumping to the last generated row if that is possible.

I don't know what function could be used.

I know that i can move to a specified cell

with 
`'  ActiveSheet.Cells(yColumn, xRow).Select
' This selects C5 on the active sheet:
ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 3).Select`

Any tips are greatly appreciated ; )

Answer (score 1):

I can think about some ways to keep track of the latest entry for each columns.

- **Color the cell in red for instance**

> Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

- **Store the row number in an other cell**

> Range("A1").Value = ActiveCell.Row

- **Use defined names**

Let's say you are going to call your latest entry cell "LastEntry"

> ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="LastEntry", RefersTo:=ActiveCell

Then, it is pretty straight forward to search.